# Creating a CAPTCHA with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I'm trying to get my registration page to display a CAPTCHA. I have a registration controller and a registration view.

Here's my controllers index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $cap = create_captcha(array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => 'http://localhost/captcha/',
        'img_width' => 150,
        'img_height' => 40
    ));
    $data = array(
        'captcha_time' => $cap['time'],
        'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
        'word' => $cap['word']
    );
    $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $data);
    $this->db->query($query);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('register', $cap);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

And the relevant bit from my register view (`register.php`):

```
<h3>Security question</h3>
<li>
    <label for="captcha">Enter the CAPTCHA code below</label>
    <?php echo $cap['image']; ?>
</li>
```

Problem is, I'm getting this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: cap
Filename: views/register.php
Line Number: 35
```

After looking at the user guide it seems the data I pass from my controller to my view needs to be an array or an object, and the only way for me to do what I want is to have the captcha generation code in my view file, which doesn't really seem to follow the MVC pattern, does it?

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: I don't know codeigniter, but from what you write, can't you just do `$this->load->view('register', array('cap'=>$cap));`? Then you're passing an array with named values (which I suspect is what the view method wants)

Comment: I tried that already, I'm still getting the `Undefined variable: cap` error.

Comment: If you have the answer, post it as an answer and mark it as answered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571804/codeigniter-captcha-validation?answertab=active#tab-top  check might help

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two considerations about your code:

1) I understand that is this a controller function, so if you want to pass to a View the "cap" variable should do something as this:

```
$data['cap'] = $cap;
$this->load->view('register', $data);
```

The first parameter of Loadview() function is the function name,the second is a array with all parameters that you want to send to the view, and the third parameter is if you want to return the view as a raw string (false by default).

2) If you want to follow the MVC Pattern, you should encapsulate the DB calls in the models that facilities Codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

In your lines

```
$query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $data);
$this->db->query($query);
```

I understand that you want to save the captcha information in a BBDD, isn't it?
So you should send the information with a captcha model better:

- Create a model in models/captcha_model.php :

  ```
     class Captcha_model extends CI_Model {
        function insert_captcha($captcha){
        //...
        //return true if it works; false otherwise
        }
    }
  ```
- In the controller function you can use it:

  ```
  $this->load->model('captcha_model');
  $this->captcha_model->insert_captcha($captcha);
  ```