# CodeIgniter CAPTCHA validation

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, captcha

I have created some form for inserting data into database and for checking if the data was sent from human I have used CAPTCHA which is already integrated to CI.

This is my controller:

```
    $checkrules = array(
        'img_path' => realpath(APPPATH . '../upload/checking/img') . '/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'upload/checking/img/',
        'font_path' => realpath(APPPATH . '../upload/checking/font.ttf'),
        'img_width' => 150,
        'img_height' => 30,
        'expiration' => 7200
    );

    $check = create_captcha($checkrules);
    $data['checkimg'] = $check['image'];

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[40]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'max_length[80]|prep_url|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('check', 'Check', 'required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('cms/theme', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success";
        $this->load->view('cms/theme', $data);
    }
```

My question now is what's the best way to validate CAPTCHA?

1.) Creating callback, which I have already done, but there was problem because when I send form is error with new CAPTCHA code.

2.) Inserting CAPTCHA's code into database and check from it. Problem is because there will be a lot of loading database and it will be very busy.

And second question. Is this CAPTCHA saving only .jpg pictures in folder or it can be any other format there? (I'm asking this because I want to delete this captcha's after they are used.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 * Example of captcha validation without database useage
 * Instead of it used session to store captcha value
 * The images will be deleted after the use
```

---

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','captcha'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'callback_validate_captcha');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {

        $original_string = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A', 'Z'));
        $original_string = implode("", $original_string);
        $captcha = substr(str_shuffle($original_string), 0, 6);

         //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
        $vals = array(
                'word' => $captcha,
                'img_path' => './captcha/',
                'img_url' => 'http://mycodeignitor.org/captcha/',
                'font_path' => BASEPATH.'fonts/texb.ttf',
                'img_width' => 150,
                'img_height' => 50,
                'expiration' => 7200
        );

        $cap = create_captcha($vals);
        $data['image'] = $cap['image'];

        if(file_exists(BASEPATH."../captcha/".$this->session->userdata['image']))
            unlink(BASEPATH."../captcha/".$this->session->userdata['image']);

        $this->session->set_userdata(array('captcha'=>$captcha, 'image' => $cap['time'].'.jpg'));
        $this->load->view('index_index',$data);
       }
       else
       {
            if(file_exists(BASEPATH."../captcha/".$this->session->userdata['image']))
                unlink(BASEPATH."../captcha/".$this->session->userdata['image']);

            $this->session->unset_userdata('captcha');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('image');
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
       }



}

public function validate_captcha(){
    if($this->input->post('captcha') != $this->session->userdata['captcha'])
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Wrong captcha code, hmm are you the Terminator?');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, img_path will have an image which I am supposed to save or codeIgniter will create it ? am confused how its gonna work actually

Comment: @Akhilraj N S: I have followed your steps but the captha seems not working and the form gets submited anyway.

Ihave used your callback function as it is and also tried this inseted:  if (0 !== strcmp($this->input->post('captcha'), $this->session->userdata['captcha'])) but all have the same effect.

And one last thing I tried to delete the image from the folder but I'm getting error "unlink(full-path\captcha): Permission denied".

Comment: @Deepanshu, the img_path is your folder/directory where you want the captcha images to be saved. You have to create that folder.  The image that will be save there was an image created in PHP thru captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use recaptcha which is easy to implement in codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA

Comment: Yes, is good thing to solve my problem, but in my current way not, because I need to have integrated solution in system.

Comment: this is an integrated solution

Comment: Not really, because if I try to work in offline mode this will not work.

Comment: maybe you didn't set up it correctly beacuse all keys work with localhost as the doc says: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro?hl=it-IT